# I need reviews on my algorithm that find longest consecutive sequence in binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, review

```
// Save the sequence with the maximum length
private static int max = 1;

/**
 * The method goal is to find the longest numerical sequence in binary tree
 * 
 * @param t - the tree for the searching
 * @param next - save the current sequence, the sequence to compare with the max
 */
public static void longestSeqPath(BinNode t, int next) {
    if (t == null)
        return;

    /*
     * First we check if we have any left then we check if the left node value is consecutive to the current node
     * if it is, we start with the counting
     */
    if (t.hasLeft() && t.getLeft().getValue() == t.getValue() + 1 || t.hasRight() && t.getRight().getValue() == t.getValue() + 1) {
        next++;
    } else if (next > max) {
        max = next;
        next = 1;
    }
    longestSeqPath(t.getLeft(), next);
    longestSeqPath(t.getRight(),next);

    // Note: Next is equals to 1 because we don't start to count the sequence from the first number in the sequence
}
```

Is the algorithm correct and solves the problem?
Is the algorithm effective?
Could I have done it more effectively?

I'm new here and learning how to ask questions. If there is anything to fix in the question I would love for suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't look right. To start with, you should track which child or children maintain the sequence. As it is, you are descending down both paths even if one of those paths is not sequential.

Comment: The first question is something you should be able to answer by providing test cases. And I think, but am not sure, that the word you want in your other two questions is "efficient," rather than "effective." If the program solves the problem, it's effective.

Answer (score 1):

Think of how you'd solve the same problem if you were doing it in an array:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // do all your logic here using a[i]
}
```

If you're doing an inorder traversal of a binary tree, that becomes:

```
void inorder(node)
{
    if (node == null) return;

    inorder(node.left);
    // do all your logic here, using node.value
    inorder(node.right);
}
```